# Viewing Console.log in ios simulator

Tags: ios, console, cordova, logging

Please excuse my silliness. I feel as this should be a simple problem. I am using phonegap to develop in IOS. I am wondering how come console.debug does not show up in the xcode console. How can I view any javascript error or exception in xcode console or anywhere? I am running on 4.3 IOS IPAD simulator. Thanks.

Comment: this question requires an update. fischel has the right answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can watch the console.log with a safari-browser. Open the ios-simulator or connect the ipad by usb. Open safari and take a look in the menu "developer". Choose your web-site and the web-inspector will open.

more info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Comment: Do you mean "can watch the console.log"?

Comment: Yes, I mean "can"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot. I have solved this problem by using [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/). It allows you to output console message (and much more) by simply adding a script tag to your app.

NOTE: for debug use only.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the old answer from Fischel, here is the menu on a desktop Safari that allows you to connect development tools to simulators or devices.

[image]